# Relation between roots of two different quadratic equations:

Tags: roots, quadratics

For example, $p,q$ are roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and $r,s$ are roots of $cx^2+dx+e=0$.
Then, my question is, can we find the relation between (if $p,q>r,s$ or $p,q \le r,s$, etc.) without actually finding the roots of the given quadratic equations?

Comment: It depends of $a,b,c,d,e$.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $p$ and $q$ in the first equation we have
$$(p-q)(ap+aq+b)=0$$ so we get
$$p=q$$ or $$a(p+q)+b=0$$
the same for the second equation

Comment: not always, if $p\neq q$ then $a(p+q)+b=0$